# Meteor how to safely access environment variables locally (CollectionFS S3)

Tags: meteor

I created environment variables to work safely with collectionFS, S3 uploads.

To access these variables, I created this file on the server: /server/lib/s3_keys.coffee

```
S3_keyId = process.env.S3_KEYID
S3_secretId = process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY
Meteor.methods
  s3_key: ->
    if S3_keyId
      S3_keyId
    else
      throw Error()

  s3_secret: ->
    if S3_secretId
      S3_secretId
    else
      throw Error()
```

And I access my keys like so on the client:

```
@Images = new FS.Collection("images",
  stores: [new FS.Store.S3("images",
    accessKeyId: ->
     Meteor.call(s3_key)#required if environment variables are not set
    secretAccessKey: ->
      Meteor.call(s3_secret)#required if environment variables are not set
    bucket: "immondm" #required
  )]
)
```

Is it the right way to do or is there a better, safer way?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use S3 yet but

- A store has to be defined on server side, not on client side.
- Meteor.methods are called by the client, that mean even if you don't display the answer of a call to the user it's still possible to show it by calling it manually through the web console.

I think what you need is this : [link](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

I generally worry when hardcoding values into the source files. There is a Mongodb available within Meteor - might make sense to put it into a collection that is only accessible by the server?